# Confirm initialization of variables from text file in class constructor

Tags: c++, class

I have created a class and in the constructor I do something like:

```
MyClass(string file)
{
    ifstream str;
    str.open (file, ifstream::in);

    // initialize class variables based on values from file

    str.close();
}
```

How would I know though if there was an error while reading the file and the values were not initialized correctly? Is the above the wrong way to do it? How else could I proceed if I want my variables to be initialized from a file in the constructor?

Edit, to clarify: What I am asking is in a statement like:

```
MyClass myclass("path/to/my/file.txt");
```

how could I know that everything was initialized correctly?

Comment: There's a `bool` conversion you can use, along with `bad()` etc.

Comment: But I can't return a value from the constructor, right? Unless I understood your suggestion wrong.

Comment: You can throw an exception or use a parameter to return an error.

Comment: Can't you have a class that reads the initialisation params (could be a structure) and passes them to the constructor of MyClass?

Comment: Yes, possibly, part of the question was for any alternative ways to do it, so that would be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use exceptions:

```
...
ifstream str;
str.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
// continue as before
```

Then, if your constructor throws an exception, you know something didn't work.

Another possibility is to detect the failure in the constructor and set a state variable which can be examined by the calling code.

Here are both solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

struct MyClass1 {
  int i;
  MyClass1(const char * iniFile) {
    std::ifstream in;
    in.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
    in.open(iniFile);
    in >> i;
  }
};

struct MyClass2 {
  int i;
  bool isValid;
  MyClass2(const char * iniFile) {
    try {
      std::ifstream in;
      in.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
      in.open(iniFile);
      in >> i;
      isValid = true;
    } catch(std::ios_base::failure &fail) {
      isValid = false;
    }
  }
};

int main () {
  try {
    MyClass1 mc1("somefile.txt");
  } catch(std::exception& fail) {
    std::cout << "oops 1\n";
  }

  MyClass2 mc2("somefile.txt");
  if(!mc2.isValid) {
    std::cout << "oops 2\n";
  }
}
```

Assuming that `somefile.txt` does not exist, that should print two lines of "oops".

Finally, a third possibility is to ensure that the constructor can **never fail**. In your case, you could provide default values in the `catch` block.

Comment: Thanks all, handling it with exceptions seems like the best solution for my situation, so I'll go with @Robᵩ 's

Answer (score 1):

You would check the values returned by the file in the same mannor you always would. If you're using `fread` you check the `ferror`. If you're doing an `atoi` conversion you check the return value of `atoi`. That, or you can implement exception handling.

To check the error codes outside of the file pass an int pointer or an int by reference and use that as a control throughout the constructor. When the constructor returns check that value. If at any point during the constructors execution `ferror` is not zero, your control should prevent further execution within the constructor.

Comment: I think the OP wants to check for error _outside_ the constructor.

Comment: @Aesthete The concept is still essentially the same but I'll add an update.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use an exception as Rob has already answered.

Another option, would be to pass a reference to a success flag.

```
MyClass(std::string filename, bool& success)
{
  success = true;
  if(!str.open(filename))
  {
    success = false;
  }      
}
```

Check for success like so.

```
bool success;
MyClass("filename", success);
if(!success)
{
  // Something failed during the class instantiation.
}
```